# How can I set the value of a UILabel following a segue?

Tags: ios

I have a simple storyboard consisting of two UIViewControllers, with a segue connecting them.

UIVC1 --> UIVC2

I'm trying to set a UILabel on UIVC2 to be equal to a string stored in UIVC1. I'm trying to pass the string in the `prepareForSegue` method, and thus far I've set it to a `property` in UIVC2.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setDesc:[Brain description]];
    }
}
```

The property in UIVC2 is `desc.`

Then, in my `setDesc` method, which I've implemented, I run `self.display.text = self.desc` where `display` is my property for the UILabel.

However, this is not working, and even when I just NSLog the value of the UILabel, it doesn't print anything, which makes me wonder if the controller is even communicating with the UILabel... (I did do the ctr+click and drag thing in the storyboard to hook them up.)

Is there a better way to do this??

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your UILabel text is not being set because `prepareForSegue` is being called before the IBOutlet for your label on the destination view controller is connected.  So at that point the label is still `nil` (and sending a message to `nil` has no effect.)

What you should do instead is to create a new property on your destination view controller to store the string, and set this property in `prepareForSegue`.  Then in your destination view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, use the value of that property to set the `text` property of your UILabel.

Comment: I'm finding the same problem and what I find confussing is that I can set the text to an outleted Button with [destController.button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal]   however with labels do not work. What is the diference?

Comment: I would check to make sure that your label is not `nil` at the time you are trying to set its text.